# Installing virtualmin over webmin

Tags: centos, software-installation, webmin

I'm setting up a CentOS 6 server, and I need to install virtualmin.

The server already comes with webmin setup, but there's no way I can see how to access virtualmin, so I assume it's not been set up yet.

I went to this page - http://www.virtualmin.com/download.html - and downloaded and ran the `install.sh` script.

However, confusingly, the instructions at the page say that after the completion of the script I should just navigate to https://{my IP address}:10000, and I'll see virtualmin. This is baffling to me, because this is the same address for the **webmin** page, and to my not very great surprise, it is the webmin page I am taken to when I navigate to that address.

Can anyone provide clarity on how exactly I am supposed to access virtualmin after running the install script?

Answer (score 0):

The trick was not to enter my IP address in http://{my IP address}:10000, but instead to use the hostname that I get when I type in `hostname` at the command prompt of the shell running the server.